# Unable to run spark job from EMR which connects to Cassandra on EC2

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, cassandra, emr

I'm running spark job from EMR cluster which connects to Cassandra on EC2

The following are the dependencies which I'm using for my project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
     <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
     <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
 </dependency>
```

The issue that Im facing here is if I use the cassandra-driver-core 3.0.0 , I get the following error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at mobi.vserv.SparkAutomation.DriverTester.doTest(DriverTester.java:28)
at mobi.vserv.SparkAutomation.DriverTester.main(DriverTester.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Detected Guava issue #1635 which indicates that a version of Guava less than 16.01 is in use.  This introduces codec resolution issues and potentially other incompatibility issues in the driver.  Please upgrade to Guava 16.01 or later.
at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.checkGuava(SanityChecks.java:62)
at com.datastax.driver.core.SanityChecks.check(SanityChecks.java:36)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<clinit>(Cluster.java:67)
... 2 more
```

I have tried including the guaua version 19.0.0 also but still I'm unable to run the job

and when I degrate the cassandra-driver-core 2.1.6 I get the following error.

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All    host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /EMR PUBLIC IP:9042    (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/EMR PUBLIC IP:9042] Cannot       connect))
 at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:223)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:78)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1272)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:158)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:248)
```

Please note that I have tested my code locally and it runs absolutely fine and I have followed the different combinations of dependencies as mentioned here https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

Code :

```
 public class App1 {

 private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App1.class);

static SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkAutomation").setMaster("yarn-cluster");


static JavaSparkContext sc = null;
static
   {

    sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
   }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JavaRDD<String> Data = sc.textFile("S3 PATH TO GZ FILE/*.gz");

    JavaRDD<UserSetGet> usgRDD1=Data.map(new ConverLineToUSerProfile());

     List<UserSetGet> t3 = usgRDD1.collect(); 

     for(int i =0 ; i <=t3.size();i++){
         try{
         phpcallone php = new phpcallone();
         php.sendRequest(t3.get(i));
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             logger.error("This Has reached ====> " + e);
         }

     }

  } 
}




public class phpcallone{

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(phpcallone.class);
static String pid;

public void sendRequest(UserSetGet usg) throws JSONException, IOException, InterruptedException {


     UpdateCassandra uc= new UpdateCassandra(); 
     try { 
         uc.UpdateCsrd(); 
         }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); }
     }

}
   }

public class UpdateCassandra{
public void UpdateCsrd() throws ClassNotFoundException {

     Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoint("PUBLIC IP ").withPort(9042)
                .withCredentials("username", "password");
     clusterBuilder.getConfiguration().getSocketOptions().setConnectTimeoutMillis(10000);

    try  {
        Session session = clusterBuilder.build().connect("dmp");
        session.execute("USE dmp");
        System.out.println("Connection established");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

 }
```

Comment: for Spark 1.6, you need 3.x version of Cassandra Driver but in your maven scripts you are still using 2.x version of Driver.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I have used 3.0.0 version of cassandra driver as well as this gives me guaua error , and when I use downgrade the cassandra driver version I get NoHostAvailableException , all the errors are mentioned in my post

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using EMR 4.1+, you can pass in the guava jar into the --jars option for spark submit. Then supply a configuration file to EMR to use user class paths first.

For example, in a file setup.json

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.driver.userClassPathFirst": "true",
      "spark.executor.userClassPathFirst": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

You would supply the --configurations file://setup.json option into the create-cluster aws cli command.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However I am facing another issue. Adding userClassPathFirst lead to a cascading issue.  Lost task 2.1 in stage 2.0 (TID 6, ip-10-187-78-197.ec2.internal): java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of org/apache/spark/util/ChildFirstURLClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/slf4j/Logger"  Any solution?

Comment: Same issue @lazywiz